# ¿Cómo puedo añadir mas de una sombra a un elemento html sin que se sobrescriban? (usando css)

Tags: html, css

estoy tratando de dar un efecto 3D con las sombras a un elemento html pero para eso me gustaría poder añadir sombras a los diferentes lados de mi elemento html, sin embargo el código se sobrescribe debido a que css es en cascada. ¿alguna idea?.

Como pueden ver el DIV ya tiene sombras pero quiero añadir mas

PD: soy un poco inexperto en css

[image: Ejemplo de un div que quiero decorar, como pueden ver ya tiene sombras pero quiero añadir mas]

Comment: [es.so] te da las herramientas necesarias para compartir tu código _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Pulsa en [edit] para corregir tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) permite ingresar más de una sombra si la separas por coma.

```css
div{
width:200px;
height:200px;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px blue, 
10px -10px 0px -3px rgb(255, 255, 255) ,
10px -10px rgb(31, 193, 27), 
20px -20px 0px -3px rgb(255, 255, 255), 
20px -20px rgb(255, 217, 19), 
30px -30px 0px -3px rgb(255, 255, 255) , 
30px -30px rgb(255, 156, 85), 
40px -40px 0px -3px rgb(255, 255, 255), 
40px -40px rgb(255, 85, 85);
}
```

```html
<div><div>
```